# Excel COPY PASTE value using macro

Tags: excel, copy

I need to copy cell value from one cell to other.

Here is the code worked

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Range("K5").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B12").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Need to copy K5 cell data to sheet1 b12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Range("K5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").Pastespecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Range("K5").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

**NOTE**:

The Selects are not necessary.